# What would be the "hello world" program of computer networks?

Tags: network-programming

I'm looking to learn more about computer networks, only I don't know how to start. What would be the equivalent of a "Hello World" program in this domain?

Comment: I obviously disagree. But if you could write a book on "Hello World" networking programs that would better answer my question than a quick answer on this site, good on you. Ping works, thank you @STLDeveloper.

Comment: I think this question was constructive, and will help others when they are also beginning network programming. There is nothing that my question goes against in that "how-to-ask" which I've already gone over. The only reason this was closed was because I was less-than-friendly to you after you said something that was in my opinion, stupid. Fair enough, I got my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "ping" utility fits the bill.

Answer (score 1):

Learn about the [Open Systems Interconnection (OSI) model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model) to understand how networks work first of all, from the Physical layer (network hardware) up to the Application layer (software protocols). Once you understand them you can use Network Analysis tools (such as Wireshark) or terminal in *nix and DOS in Windows OS to carry out various operations at each layer in the OSI.